# How to add php code in custom blocks in drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

I have a drupal 8 fresh installation, I need to add some php code such as getting base url in custom blocks.
Please guide me in acheiving this.
Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)  if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question.](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 1):

PHP filter is a core module in Drupal 7 but in Drupal 8 it is removed because of some security reason.

You could and should do your PHP logic with [template_preprocess_block](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7.x). As creating a programmatic block just so you can use PHP is more work than necessary, overkill, for this use case.

Also, without any more specific info regarding make them dynamic based on base URL, this is as far as I can go.

Comment: Hi Moby,
thanks for reply and solution,
Need some more clarification,
As per my understanding, we need to create a custom module for creating a custom block,
if so, i need to add base_url in almost every block, so for every block we need to create a module ?
please suggest